# Do objects with SqlConnecions as private fields get closed if the object is in an using block?

Tags: c#, object, dispose, using, using-directives

I know that using an SqlConnection inside a using block like below will close the connection at the end of the using block.

```
using (var connection = factory.NewSqlConnection())
{
    //code
}
```

I want to know if an object that has a SqlConnection private field, and is used in a using statement will also close the connection like so:

```
using (var db = factory.NewDatabaseManager())
{
    //code
} 

public class DatabaseManager
{
    private SqlConnection _connection;

    public DatabaseManager(SqlConnection connection)
    {
         _connection = connection;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not an attribute, it's just a private field. You should implement IDisposable in DatabaseManager and dispose connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the `DatabaseManager` class is used inside of a `using` statement, so it must implement `IDisposable`, and therefore has a `Dispose` method of its own.

In that case, the `SqlConnection` object will be disposed only if the `Dispose` method in your `DatabaseManager` class calls the `SqlConnection` object's `Dispose` method.  There's no magic that makes this happen. Your code has to manage the `SqlConnection` properly or you will have problems.

Comment: DatabaseManager does not implement IDisposable, should it?

Comment: If you're going to use it in a `using` statement, it has to.  The compiler won't let you use it in a `using` statement unless it implements `IDisposable`.  And given what you're trying to do, it definitely should.

Comment: Don't forget to close the sql connection on the dispose method of your DatabaseManager class like Tony said.

Answer (score 2):

It can but you have to write the code to do it. Here is your example with the DatabaseManager now implementing IDisposable. Before the using statement would have given you a compile time error because it did not implement that.

Also the `_connection` below is called a `field`, not an `attribute` which is something else entirely.

Before you start to implement IDisposable in your types please refer to the proper way to implement IDisposable, like it should never throw an exception. Here is the [Microsoft take on the Dispose pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.110).aspx), its a great checklist of what to do and what to avoid.

```
using (DatabaseManager db = factory.NewDatabaseManager())
{
    //code
} 

public class DatabaseManager : IDisposable
{
    private SqlConnection _connection;

    public DatabaseManager(SqlConnection connection)
    {
         _connection = connection;
    }

    // basic implementation of IDisposable
    public void Dispose() {
        _connection.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: That link to the MSDN article on how to implement the Disposable pattern is handy and something I hadn't read before.